# jquery change variable from inside if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-animate

I have some different variables at the top of my document. 
At some point I change one of the inside an if statement. 
The variable that I'm changing is used to calculate another variable, so I was thinking that should change the other one to?

When I try to use the variable that has been calculated with the change one it does not give me the the wanted result. I'm trying to make a man jump differently.

As a standard the ground height (where the man is walking) is 120, witch means that he is 120px away from the bottom. I can make him jump, this takes a little more variables, first the jump height, that is 180. - The jump height and the ground height is added to calculate the actually jump so in this case it animates the man's bottom position from 120 to 300 px.

The fall or the down force of the jump is calculated by jump - jump height this leaving only the ground height back so his bottom position is animated back to 120 px.

My idea was to change the ground height to 200 px and then when he falls down he in only falling to 200px instead of 120 px.

The whole thing is to make an illusion of a man jumping up on a box.

**Question**: Why does the fall variable not change, when it gets a new number to calculate with

Here are my variables:

```
var ground_height = 120;
var jump_height = 180;
var jump = ground_height + jump_height;
var fall = jump - jump_height;
```

Here is my jump:

```
        if(keyStack[32]) {
        if(!man.data('lock')) {
            man.data('lock', true);
                man.stop().animate(
                    {
                        bottom: jump + 'px'
                    },
                    800,
                    function() {
                        man.stop().animate({
                            bottom: fall + 'px'
                        }, 400, function() {
                            man.data('lock', false);   
                        });
                    }
                );
        }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3frbL/1/)
(use arrows keys to go right and left, and spacebar for jumping)

Comment: Why it dont change the fall variable, as it get a new number to calculate with?

Comment: As far as i can see from your fiddle code you only set the fall var once so I don't see where you expect it to get changed

Comment: Yup, forgot that, sorry for you time :)